# I am trying to mutate specific variables within a data frame using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, describe

I'm trying to mutate variables in a data frame that has 10 of the 55 variables in the dataset that I'm using. 5 of those 10 variables are categorical and as such, I am trying to convert them into factors (as characters). However, every time R does the mutation, it applies the mutation to those 5 factors as if I never put them into a separate data frame. R will only apply the mutation onto them in the entire group of 55 variables. I've highlighted and rerun the code as a whole and for each variable individually multiple times and it still won't work. When I use the (view) function on the ten variables I want and hover each of the variable names in the table displayed, the mutations go away for some reason, as if I didn't do them. When I use (view) on the entire dataset and do the same, the mutations are there. I've created multiple data frames just trying to get this to work. I thought maybe I had to move the variables again and then the mutations would show up, but that hasn't been the case.

Now I'm also running into the issue of R only applying one mutation. If I try to mutate the variable "qualslp" from numerical to character and then do the same to the variable "sex" r gets rid of the mutation on "qualslp" and it reverts back to numerical, while "sex" becomes a character vector.

Code and screenshots provided below.

[screenshot of 55 variables with the one mutation (underlined in yellow)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsqWd.png)

[screenshot of the data frame (underlined in yellow) containing the 10 variables that I want to use the mutate function on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S327c.png)

```
sleepdata_nvars <-select(sleepdata,
                     age, sex, alchohol, smokenum, liteslp, wakenite, medhelp, qualslp, depress, ess)

sleepdata_nvars <- mutate(sleepdata,
                      sex = as.character(sex),
                      sex = fct_recode(sex,
                                       "female" = "0",
                                       "male" = "1"))
sleepdata_nvars <- mutate(sleepdata,
                      liteslp = as.character(liteslp),
                      liteslp = fct_recode(liteslp,
                                       "yes" = "1",
                                       "no" = "2"))
sleepdata_nvars <- mutate(sleepdata,
                      wakenite = as.character(wakenite),
                      wakenite = fct_recode(wakenite,
                                       "yes" = "1",
                                       "no" = "2"))
sleepdata_nvars <- mutate(sleepdata,
                      medhelp = as.character(medhelp),
                      medhelp = fct_recode(medhelp,
                                       "yes" = "1",
                                       "no" = "2"))
sleepdata_nvars <- mutate(sleepdata,
                      qualslp = as.character(qualslp),
                      qualslp = fct_recode(qualslp,
                                       "very poor" = "1",
                                       "poor" = "2",
                                       "fair"= "3",
                                       "good" = "4",
                                       "very good" = "5",
                                       "excellent" = "6"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including example data in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(yourdata)`. We cannot copy/paste data from images.

Comment: Use `mutate(sleepdata_nvars, ...`. Your current code keeps going back to the original instead of continuing from the modified dataset.

Comment: @MichaelDewar This worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comment by @MichaelDewar I think the issue is that you should just use one `mutate` statement, and chain it to the original `select`.

```
sleepdata_nvars <- sleepdata %>%
  select(age, sex, alchohol, smokenum, liteslp, 
         wakenite, medhelp, qualslp, depress, ess) %>%
  mutate(sex = as.character(sex),
         sex = fct_recode(sex,
                          "female" = "0",
                          "male" = "1"),
         liteslp = as.character(liteslp),
         liteslp = fct_recode(liteslp,
                              "yes" = "1",
                              "no" = "2"),
         wakenite = as.character(wakenite),
         wakenite = fct_recode(wakenite,
                               "yes" = "1",
                               "no" = "2"),
         medhelp = as.character(medhelp),
         medhelp = fct_recode(medhelp,
                              "yes" = "1",
                              "no" = "2"),
         qualslp = as.character(qualslp),
         qualslp = fct_recode(qualslp,
                              "very poor" = "1",
                              "poor" = "2",
                              "fair"= "3",
                              "good" = "4",
                              "very good" = "5",
                              "excellent" = "6")
)
```

Comment: Right, yes. My professor and TA both demonstrate that version of doing this as it's more efficient. The reason I didn't is that I'm still new to and very uncomfortable using R, so I like to do things the long way almost as a way of spelling it out for myself. But hopefully, I'll become more confident and efficient in coding as time goes on! Thank you!